# Unable to register MBean for ws-outbound-gateway

Tags: java, spring-integration, jmx

The integration flow uses the following:

```
<int:chain input-channel="input" id="inChain">
        <!-- some header-enrichers -->
        <int-ws:outbound-gateway id="outGateway"/> <!-- other properties are omitted -->               
</int:chain>
```

In the process of deploying to Tomcat, i get an error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException:
Unable to register MBean [inChain$child.outGateway.handler] with key 'inChain$child.outGateway.handler'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExportException:
Could not create ModelMBean for managed resource [inChain$child.outGateway.handler] with key 'inChain$child.outGateway.handler';
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler does not support JDK dynamic proxies - export the target beans directly or use CGLIB proxies instead.
```

Is there a simple solution in spring integration or is it necessary to follow the advice from the error text (make a custom MBeanExporter and so on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be better to think not making that gateway as a proxy at all? How that happen though? Nothing confirms in your question that there is a story about proxying... on the other hand you can exclude that bean from JMX exporting. Or you can provide an other way to gather MBean info for that bean. See how you can customize `MBeanExporter`.

Or you just can add an `IntegrationMBeanExporter`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jmx.html#jmx-mbean-exporter

Comment: "May be better to think not making that gateway as a proxy at all?" - that would be great! If this is the default behavior, then how to cancel it, and if it is set forcibly, then what is it regulated by (this is a third-party project)? Thanx in advance.

Comment: No, it is not by default. Apparently there is some AOP advice which we are not aware of from your question. You may consider to turn off JMX at all

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Artem Bilan for search direction: found AOP advice in code:

```
<bean id="interceptor" class="..."/>
<aop:config>
   <aop:pointcut id="all" expression="execution(*org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(..))"/>
   <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="all" advice-ref="interceptor" order="1"/>
</aop:config>
```

The best solution for now is to disable JMX.